# Lightswitch Desktop DataGrid "Enter" like "TAB"

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013, lightswitch-2012

I need to override the behavior of the "Enter" key in the DataGrid. I need to TAB with the enter key inside the DataGrid. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: In which client? HTML or Silverlight?

Comment: Hi, i need this in the silverlight desktop client.